# Getting nice PostgreSQL pgAdmin-style DDL

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, schema-copy

In pgAdmin 3 (and pgAdmin 4 if you're prepared to wait longer) the DDL for the currently selected database object is shown in the main panel, along with corresponding triggers, constraints, etc, all nicely formatted. It looks quite different to the DDL exported from pgdump. Is there a way to get the nicer version, without manually copy-and-pasting from pgAdmin?

Comment: AFAIK, the answer is *no, there's not such a tool*.

Comment: The functions like `pg_get_functiondef` and `pg_get_viewdef` don't do the same pretty-printing PgAdmin does, so no, I don't think so.

Comment: Maybe you could fo your pg_dump for all DDL and then pipe it to a formatting tool like https://github.com/darold/pgFormatter ?

Comment: @KookieMonster Thanks for the pgFormatter link - very nice. But what I like about the pgAdmin approach is that it groups related DDL statements together as a conceptual unit. I've located the code that does these steps now (as an answer to my own question) so maybe I'll get around to scripting up as you suggest, next time I find some Copious Free Time...

Comment: One idea could be pg_dump --schema-only mybase | pgformatter > mydumpfile and after pg_dump --data-only mybase >> mydumpfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digging around in the pgAdmin source code it appears that the routines to generate the DDL are embedded within the application code. For instance, I the code to generate the table DDL can be found in [`pgTable::GetSql`](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=pgadmin3.git;a=blob;f=pgadmin/schema/pgTable.cpp;h=fdfea400cb1ef7f37f85ad74da8f7c4f9062fb05;hb=HEAD#l324).